# recontar terminos de woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

tengo un script en php que me importa productos desde un .csv a la base de datos,el problema es que cuando finalizo necesito ir al apartado de wordpress/woocommerce/Estado/Herramientas/Recontar Terminos para que refresque en la pagina web lo productos.Alguna idea para solucionarlo?
Gracias!

Comment: Por favor no repitas las preguntas. Actualiza la pregunta que hiciste originalmente y trabaja sobre ella